# How to show an ever-visible footer near Windows status bar?

Tags: html, css

I saw similar posts in this forum but there were no replies.

I have a grey colored band (a DIV) on which I have links for site navigation. At present, it is displayed at the end of the page, when you just scroll down to the end. I want it to remain visible like the Windows status bar and at the same position like the status bar.

Even if the user scrolls the site, this band must remain at that position.

Comment: Retagged from `asp.net` since this is only concerned with the resulting HTML, hence not ASP-related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS style `position: fixed;` is what you're looking for. Additionally set `bottom: 0px;` and `width`, `height` and `left` to whatever values you want.

Answer (score 2):

`position: fixed` in the CSS will do it, although this isn't supported in IE 6 if that's important to you. If it is, have a look at http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ for something similar cross-browser or use a script like [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to add fixed positioning to IE 6.